# How do I find last updated files since 1 week?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a directory and there are about ~1000 files in there. 
I want to get the file names which last updated since 7 days? And write this file names to another file.
I'm using windows 2012 and I want to do that with batch script. How may I do that?

UPDATE:
I tried

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=c:\some\where"
(  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
      robocopy "%folder%" "%folder%" * /l /nocopy /is /maxage:7 /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl 
   ') do echo(%%a
) > outputFile.txt
```

However, I receive this error:

```
ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.
Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
/MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.
For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
```

**** /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder=c:\some\where"
    (  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
          robocopy "%folder%" "%folder%" * /l /nocopy /is /maxage:7 /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl 
       ') do echo(%%a
    ) > outputFile.txt
```

This uses `robocopy` command to retrieve the list of the required files. It will only list `/l`, without copying anything `/nocopy`, all the files, including those considered the same file `/is`, with a max age of 7 days `/maxage:7`, without headers `/njh`, summary `/njs`, file class `/nc`, size `/ns` or directory listing `/ndl`.

The output of the command will include some blank columns that are removed with the `for` loop.